# Get list of users belonging to particular projects in TFS 2013

Tags: visual-studio, tfs

How to get the list of users belonging to particular projects in TFS 2013 via query if possible?  Like If i have a list of users and i want to know that these users belong to X or y project in TFS.

Answer (score 0):

You can't achieve this via query.

1. An easy way is go to admin security page of a Team Project Collection http://tfsserver:8080/tfs/CollectionName/_admin/_security, and click `Users` to check which team project the users belong to:

[image]

2. Another way is to use TFS API to retrieve this information. Check this blog: http://geekswithblogs.net/TarunArora/archive/2011/09/30/tfs-sdk-get-groups-users-permissions-using-tfs-api-with.aspx